# Uber sandbox'ed /requests endpoint uses production environment and call real drivers

Tags: api, request, sandbox, uber-api

This behavior started today (11/10/2015). 
When I make a call to sandboxed Uber endpoint a real driver accept and comes.

I've spent 5 hours trying to understand what is happening.
I've been using Uber API for last 1.5 months and haven't had this issue before.

I make this request (now I do it with Postman, so seems like there is nothing else can affect it):

```
URL: https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests
Method: POST
Headers: 
    Authorization Bearer AvwkOYENiYRS... (Got it from Uber)
    Content-Type: application/json
body: 
    {
        "product_id": "04a497f5-380d-47f2-bf1b-ad4cfdcb51f2", // got from uber before that
        "start_latitude":37.4237323,
        "start_longitude":-122.09827279999999,
        "end_latitude":37.4243272,
        "end_longitude":-122.09491579999997
    }
```

I receive successful response from Uber.
And after some time server start receiving events from Uber:

```
X-Environment: production
{
    ...
    "event_type": "requests.status_changed",
    "meta": {
        "resource_id": "...", // resource_id that I get when requested sandboxed api
        "status": "accepted" // and then arriving, etc
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug on Uber's side. This was resolved this morning. Let us know if you still see the issue.